# Fourier transform of single and double slit functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to calculate the fourier transforms of these functions

single slit:
$$
f(x)=1 
$$
with $
\frac{-b}{2}<x<\frac{b}{2}
$

and $
f(x)=0 
$ elsewhere

double slit:
$$
f(x)=1 
$$
with $
\frac{-(g+b)}{2}<x<\frac{-(g-b)}{2}, \frac{(g-b)}{2}<x<\frac{(g+b)}{2}
$

and $
f(x)=0 
$ elsewhere

where b gives the slit width and g the slit distance.

For the single slit, using the definition of a fourier transform, the result for $f(x)=1$ must be the delta function, with $x_0=0$, so $\delta(x)$, right? and still $0$ elsewhere.

for the double slit, again using the definition of fourier transform, is it correct to say that 
$$
F(k)=\delta(x+g), F(k)=\delta(x-g), 
$$ 
with $F(k)=0$ elsewhere.

Is this correct? Is there a more intuitive way of looking at the results of this? I Think i've done the maths correctly but

Answer (score 2):

You are not correct. The Fourier transform is absolutely **not** a delta function, since $f(x)$ isn't constant everywhere.

There are several definitions of the Fourier transform. I don't know which one you use, so I'll use mine

$$ F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi ik x} dx = \int_{-b/2}^{b/2}e^{-2\pi ik x} dx = \frac{e^{\pi ik b}-e^{\pi ik b}}{2\pi ik} = \frac{\sin(b\pi k)}{\pi k} = b \operatorname{sinc}(b\pi k) $$

For the double-slit, we invoke the Fourier shift theorem
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-g)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-2\pi ik(x+g)} dx = e^{-2\pi ig k} F(k) $$

So the transform turns out to be
$$ F(k) = \big( e^{2\pi i gk} + e^{-2\pi i gk}\big)b\operatorname{sinc}(b\pi k) = 2b\cos(2\pi gk)\operatorname{sinc}(b\pi k) $$

Comment: I believe the answer for the single-slit above is correct, but the answer for the double-slit above should be for $f(x)=\theta\left(x+\frac{b+g}{2}\right)-\theta\left(x+\frac{g-b}{2}\right)+\theta\left(x-\frac{g-b}{2}\right)-\theta\left(x-\frac{b+g}{2}\right)$, $\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,e^{-2\,\pi\,i\,x\,\omega}\,dx=2\,b \cos(\pi\,g\,\omega)\,sinc(\pi\,b\,\omega)$ which omits the factor of $2$ inside the $cos$ function.